Lighthouse PWA audit looks like it does not work in Chrome 126 (shows empty screen)
I'm just starting to dive into the world of progressive web apps. A lot of tutorials highlight the PWA audit of Lighthouse (Version 12.0.0) in Google Chrome. If I start Google Chrome (Version 126.0.6478.127), open an https website, run the developer tools, go on the Lighthouse tap, check "progressive web app" (and none of the other categories) and analyse the site, the tool returns an empty page. If I check other categories as well, such as SEO, I receive the audits of this categories, but no PWA audit.
When checking the documentations of Lighthouse I found the information "PWA testing in Lighthouse is deprecated. For more information on its deprecation see Chrome's updated Installability Criteria."
Firstly, I would be interested to know whether this behaviour (which seems faulty to me) is normal in the current Lighthouse version. And secondly, if this is the case, I would be interested to know what alternative test options are available.

It was removed from Lighthouse: https://x.com/JLarky/status/1806196699704270858

Thanks for the answer. In the UI it is still available, which was confusing to me. But I guess, this is the write answer. Thanks!

It is but reports are not available anymore

Change with links here

@Stetzon, any suggestion to have this feature back?

In my case, the PWA feature in lighthouse audit doesn't exist

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
